# When to create a new asset volume?

Tags: assets, volumes

I'm not sure if I've been using asset volumes correctly.

For each folder inside my `/uploads` directory, I've been creating a new volume. So they're all relative to `/uploads`

I have volumes for things like blog, general, locations, brochures, etc.

so folder structure is like:

```
 - Uploads
    - general
    - blog
        - subfolder
    - locations
    - brochures
```

Should I just have a single Volume called "uploads" and then create the subfolders within the craft dashboard via Assets?

Is there a downside in creating a volume per folder?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I just have a single Volume called "uploads" and then create the subfolders within the craft dashboard via Assets?

I think that's typically how people would set it up.  You might run into some edge-case synchronization issues with nested Volumes.

Comment: thanks, brad. I ended up downsizing my volumes from like 8 to 2. (Image Uploads,and PDFs). Much more manageable. I think at the time of making all the volumes I didn't realize you could create folders in the craft assets view.